# Express Auth - Session middleware to check the user is authenticated

Tags: node.js, express.js, jwt

I am building an API with Express and NodeJS.

I have made this middleware to check before executing my controller, that the user is logged in. It has taken me quite a while and I would like if another pair of eyes would take a look and tell me if I have missed something important.

I am not really looking for advice on how to write this cleaner. It is just more about the use cases, or if the way each case is handled.

```js
const { orgService } = require("../services");
const { verifyAccessToken } = require("../services/authService");
const userService = require("../services/userService");

const { JWT_SECRET } = process.env;

// Middleware for loading the session data, based on the cookies sent.
// At the end, we move on to the next middleware function in the chain
const sessionMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log("sessionMiddleware running...");

        // Getting the access token from the cookies
        const { accessToken } = req.cookies;

        // If there's no access token, return an error
        if (!accessToken) {
            res.clearCookie("accessToken");
            return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized", code: "NO_ACCESS_TOKEN" });
        }

        // Verifying the access token
        let decodedToken;

        try {
            decodedToken = verifyAccessToken(accessToken, JWT_SECRET);
        } catch (error) {
            res.clearCookie("accessToken");

            // If the access token is expired, return an error
            if (error.name === "TokenExpiredError")
                return res.status(401).json({ error: "Access token expired", code: "ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED" });

            // If the access token is invalid, return an error
            return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized", code: "INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN" });
        }

        // Getting the user ID from the access token
        const { userId } = decodedToken;

        // If the access token is invalid, return an error
        if (!userId) {
            res.clearCookie("accessToken");
            return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized", code: "INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN" });
        }

        // If the access token is valid, load the user and profile data
        req.user = await userService.findFirst({ where: { id: userId }, include: { profile: true } });

        // If there's no user, return an error
        if (!req.user) {
            res.clearCookie("accessToken");
            return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized", code: "USER_NOT_FOUND" });
        }

        // Getting the active organization ID from the cookies
        // This information is not mandatory to have a valid session
        const activeOrganizationId = parseInt(req.cookies.activeOrganizationId);

        // If there's no active organization ID, move on
        if (!activeOrganizationId) return next();

        // load the organization data if the user is a member of the organization
        const activeOrganization = await orgService.findFirst({
            where: { id: activeOrganizationId, ownerId: userId },
        });

        // If there's no organization, move on
        if (!activeOrganization) return next();

        // If there's an organization, add it to the request object
        req.activeOrganization = activeOrganization;

        // Move on to the next middleware function in the chain
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.clearCookie("accessToken");
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized", code: "SESSION_MIDDLEWARE_ERROR" });
    }
};

exports.sessionMiddleware = sessionMiddleware;
```